# rsync non-ascii characters

Tags: shell-script, rsync, filenames

I am using rsync to backup my website files, using --link-dest to copy from the previous rsync backup.

```
rsync -zavx -e 'ssh -p22' \
   --numeric-ids \
   --delete -r \
   --link-dest=../"$latest_backup" "$rhost:$rhost_source" "$local_dest";
```

I have noticed that files with non-ascii characters look to have had their characters converted, so the rsync is deleting them and then re-downloading them.

Here is an example:

```
deleting public_html/images/made/96096a4645d59a3e/Moulin_a?\#200_vent_Bourgogne_DBW1901_680_680_s_c1.jpg

public_html/images/made/96096a4645d59a3e/Moulin_à_vent_Bourgogne_DBW1901_1200_801_80.jpg
```

Is it possible to stop rsync from converting the characters?

Comment: What kind of filesystems are used on the source and target here?

Comment: Sorry @Kusalananda, what do you mean by filesystem?

Comment: Is one filesystem NTFS and another ext4 or exFAT, or something similar?

Comment: The source is a linux server and the destination a Mac computer. Does that help?

Comment: @roaima both are just paths

Comment: @roaima Sorry, I have just understood what you meant. The $site_source is a host:path. I am connecting via SSH.

Answer (score 6):

Need to use `--iconv`.

From the man page https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

```
--iconv=CONVERT_SPEC 
 Rsync can convert filenames between character sets using this option. 
 Using a CONVERT_SPEC of lq.rq tells rsync to
 look up the default character-set via the locale setting. Alternately,
 you can fully specify what conversion to do by giving a local and a
 remote charset separated by a comma in the order --iconv=LOCAL,REMOTE,
 e.g. --iconv=utf8,iso88591. This order ensures that the option will
 stay the same whether you're pushing or pulling files. Finally, you
 can specify either --no-iconv or a CONVERT_SPEC of lq-rq to turn off
 any conversion. The default setting of this option is site-specific,
 and can also be affected via the RSYNC_ICONV environment variable.
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. I have tried adding '--iconv=us-ascii,utf8' to my rsync, but I am getting 'unknown option' returned. As far as I can tell, files stored on my server are 'utf8' and 'us-ascii' on my Mac.

Comment: `--iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8`, or vice-versa ?

Comment: you need rsync 3.something to have the `iconv` option.  The default rsync version on mac is 2.6.x